# Editing Line Spacing For DataGridView In Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

I am currently using a DataGridView in VB where I am using multi-line text in a single cell, both by enabling wrapping property and inserting 'Environment.NewLine' between the separated text within the cell. This works fine but I am trying to see If I can get more space between the lines in the cell without having to add another empty row. When adding another row it seems to be too much space. My goal is similar to how line spacing works in Word or Google Docs. Any Recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: The default text rendering doesn't provide interline, kerning or *paragraph* definition support. If you want to customize the text appearance, you have to draw it yourself, to create *before* and *after* line/paragraph spacing. Another possibility is to replace the standard TextBox of a TextBoxCell with a RichTextBox and handle the `PARAFORMAT2` struct (as the base structure) that defines the paragraph in a RichEdit/MSFTEdit Control. Which is not provided by default, you have to handle a Custom Control and its AdvancedTypographics options. Or handle a COM Text Object Model document.

Answer (score 0):

In design view open the properties window for your DataGridView. Click the ellipsis next to RowDefaultCellStyle. Change the value by Padding Bottom.
[image]